# Add a new column and insert specific values according to an defined intervall in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to add a new column in a pandas dataframe and insert 1 for all values <=W1, 2 for all values <=W2 and 3 for all values >W2 ?

```
W1=3
W2=6
```

This is my example case:

```
column1 number   
2       1
1       1
5       2
6       2
7       3
8       3
3       1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can double [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
W1=3
W2=6

df['d'] = np.where(df['column1'] <= W1, 1, 
          np.where(df['column1'] <= W2, 2, 3))
print (df)
   column1  number  d
0        2       1  1
1        1       1  1
2        5       2  2
3        6       2  2
4        7       3  3
5        8       3  3
6        3       1  1
```

Another solution with [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html), [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-tile-cut):

```
bins = [-np.inf, W1, W2, np.inf]
labels=[1,2,3]
df['d1'] = pd.cut(df['column1'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
print (df)

   column1  number  d d1
0        2       1  1  1
1        1       1  1  1
2        5       2  2  2
3        6       2  2  2
4        7       3  3  3
5        8       3  3  3
6        3       1  1  1
```

Answer (score 5):

```
df['new'] = df.column1.gt(W1).add(1).add(df.column1.gt(W2))

df
```

[image]

---

When `column1` is greater than `W1`, We get `True`.  Less than or equal gets `False`.  When I add `1`, Those boolean values get cast to the integer values `1` and `0` respectively.  So the result is `2` and `1` for `True` and `False` (because I added 1).  So, as of now, I have `1` for Less than or equal to `W1` and `2` for greater than `W1`.  I finish it up by adding the boolean series of when `column1` is greater than `W2` which adds `0` if less than or equal to `W2` and adds `1` to the `2`'s when `column1` is greater than `W2`.

I can show it like this to make it more obvious what it's doing

```
c = df.column1
(c > W1) + 1 + (c > W2)

0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    1
Name: column1, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an approach using [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
df['out'] = np.searchsorted([W1,W2],df.column1)+1
```

Runtime test -

```
In [230]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(10000)),columns=[['column1']])

In [231]: W1,W2 = 3,6

In [232]: %timeit np.where(df['column1'] <= W1, 1,np.where(df['column1'] <= W2, 2, 3))
1000 loops, best of 3: 633 µs per loop # @jezrael's soln

In [233]: %timeit df.column1.gt(W1).add(1).add(df.column1.gt(W2))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 ms per loop # @piRSquared's soln

In [234]: %timeit np.searchsorted([W1,W2],df.column1)+1
1000 loops, best of 3: 205 µs per loop # Using np.searchsorted
```

Use `df.column1.values`, so that `np.searchsorted` works with a NumPy array for further boost -

```
In [235]: %timeit np.searchsorted([W1,W2],df.column1.values)+1
1000 loops, best of 3: 184 µs per loop
```

Comment: awesome answer!  I'm going to imprint this idea into my head.

Comment: @piRSquared Glad to share something useful with the `pandas` gurus!